# How to get the value of NSMutableArray in viewcontroller from the appdelegate

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the NSMutableArray property in ViewController.h Now i want to get this Array value from appdelegate.
Is it possible can anyone help me to do that.

In viewcontroller.h

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *fullImg;
```

In viewcontroller.m

```
@synthesis fullImg;
```

I also assigned values for fullImg. Now i want to get that value in app delegate.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Define the relationship between the app delegate and the view controller.

Comment: Store it in NSUserDefaults and then get it from where you want to use it. But trojanfoe is probably a better answer.

Comment: You should only have code in the AppDelegate which handles Application state. Mutable arrays which are needed in view controllers should not be in the AppDelegate. This is a symptom of bad architecture.

Comment: @dasdom - No worse than using a singleton.

Comment: @HotLicks I disagree.

Comment: @dasdom - Well, I disagree with your disagreement.

Comment: @dasdom @ HotLicks you're both right. The app delegate is the same as a singleton anyway. It's only created once in the app and you can get to it from anywhere. However, having said that, there are situations that using a singleton is valid. There is never a situation IMO when using the app delegate for anything than app state is valid. Having said that, I don't think either the app delegate or a singleton is good for this question. Both would be equally as bad ... in this situation.

Comment: @Fogmeister Thanks. And I totally agree.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can put the whole NSMutableArray into NSUserDefaults with a key e.g.

In app delegate:

```
NSUserDefaults *def=[NSUserDefaults StanderUserDefaults];
[def setObject:fulImg forKey:@"ImageArray"];
```

In ViewController class:

```
NSUserDefaults *def=[NSUserDefaults StanderUserDefaults];
NSMutableArray *yourimgarry=[def valueForKey:@"ImageArray"];
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Move the array declaration from viewController to AppDelegate
2. In viewController.m do:

top file:
    #import "AppDelegate.h"

in place you want to use the array:

```
AppDelegate *ap = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
ap.fullImg // -> USE IT HOW YOU WANT 

...
```

Comment: This is really bad architecture. The AppDelegate should never be holding application data.

Answer (score 0):

When you create the object for `viewController` class, you can pass the array reference to the `viewController` by creating new custom constructor. i.e,

```
//in appdidFinishLaunchingWithOptions
ViewController *viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithArray:fullImgArray];
self.window.rootViewController = viewController;


// In ViewController.h
- (id)initWithArray:(NSMutableArray *)fullImgArray;

// In ViewController.m
- (id)initWithArray:(NSMutableArray *)fullImgArray
{
   self = [super init];

   if (self)
   {
       self.fulImg = fullImgArray;
   }
   return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities.

1. Using appDelegate. Use a property in app delegate to pass data between ViewContriollers
    and AppDelegate.

   in first controller

   MyAppdeleagte appDelegate=[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]; 
      appDelegate.fullImg=dataToPass;

   in the second controller

   MyAppdeleagte appDelegate=[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]; 
          data=appDelegate.fullImg;

   in AppDelegate

   self.fullImg=data;

2.Specifying object Instance.

in your ViewController after allocating the AppDelegate , specify that  the object instance in the current viewController is same as the one in AppDelegate. For this declare a NSMutableArray property in AppDelegate.

in AppDelegate.h

```
@property NSMutableArray *fullImg;
```

in ViewController.h

```
 MyAppdeleagte appDelegate=[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]; 

appDeleagte.fullImg=self.fullImg;
```